# glyphicon OK not displaying in internet explorer

Tags: glyphicons

Glyphicon is getting displayed in Chrome and ff but its not getting displayed in IE.
All the fonts are getting downloaded ,there are no errors.
Please provide some inputs

Comment: Please show us how you include the lib.

Comment: <li class="active" id="providerInfoTab"><a
         data-toggle="tab" href="#provider-info" class="visited-link"><span
          class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok hidden"></span>Provider
          Information</a></li>